# OpenOffice "Print" Macro Errors on close

Tags: c#, printing, macros, openoffice.org

In Open office I have created a macro for printing documents.

```
sub printDoc(FileName)
Dim Url as String
Url = convertToUrl(FileName)

Dim Doc as variant
Doc = starDeskTop.loadComponentFromUrl(Url, "_hidden", 0, Array())
Doc.Print(Array())
Doc.Close(True)
End Sub
```

I call this macro from my c# program, the macro launches and the document prints however the macro errors when it gets to the line "Doc.Close(True)" and sometimes locks up the computer until the program is ended though task manager. Is there something I should be doing differently? Please let me know if you need any additional information.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked (I have an open document function)

```
sub printDoc(FileName)
   openDoc(FileName)

 Dim opts(0) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
 opts(0).Name = "Wait"
 opts(0).Value = True
 thisComponent.Print (opts())
 If HasUnoInterfaces(ThisComponent, "com.sun.star.util.XCloseable") Then 
   ThisComponent.close(true) 
 Else 
   ThisComponent.dispose 
 End If 

End Sub
```

The important part is:

```
Dim opts(0) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
opts(0).Name = "Wait"
opts(0).Value = True
thisComponent.Print (opts())
```

this makes sure we aren't trying to close the document while we are trying to print it.

Source:
http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=40719